# Word 2010 doesn't support XML Schemes... any alternatives? (asp.net)

Tags: c#, asp.net, xsd, word-2010

I'm looking for new alternatives in creating/changing doc/docx files from word template (asp.net). In the past I was creating documents using XML schemes, but since i4i case Word 2010 don't support them. Microsoft suggests custom controls, but I have large documents with quite a few dynamically generated tables and I don't think that these controls are a good solution.

Does anyone have any alternatives similar to XML Schemes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [Open XML SDK 2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=5124) from Microsoft.
Then you can use the [Simple OOXML](http://simpleooxml.codeplex.com/) project to get you started.
Does not work for legacy office documents (i.e. doc/xls) only the new ones like docx and xslx.

hint: a docx/xslx is really a zip file full of xml documents. just change the extension to zip.